# Does Singapore Airlines offer any reward seats on their EWR-SIN route?

Tags: loyalty-programs, routes, ewr, singapore-airlines, sin

Singapore Airlines has an all-business class flight from EWR-SIN (Newark->Singapore), but I can't seem to find any reward Krisflyer flights for *any* dates.

Comment: This route (as well as LAX-SIN) is being canceled by the end of the year.

Answer (score 8):

SQ often blocks partner awards for very exclusive classes/flights - like their Suites and the EWR-SIN flight. So it will make a difference if you are trying to use SQ miles, or miles from another *A airline.

This blog post has some information in the middle that might help you: http://boardingarea.com/blogs/onemileatatime/2008/05/03/award-booking-question/

It seems to suggest that only one seat is released per flight.

e: update -

http://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/ppsclub-krisflyer/RedeemMiles_SQMI/

> Only Standard and Full awards are available for redemption of flights on the all-Business Class A340-500.

This would imply that they do release seats. I would expect, however, that demand would be pretty high.